# Is there an analog to "locate.replace()" in Silverlight 4 Navigation?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, navigation

If a user navigates to a page that displays an "add item" view (#/items/add), I want to basically skip that url when they click "back" after they save the item.

How can I do this?

Here is the behavior I'm after in more detail... if the user has navigated to and is currently on this silverlight url:

***#/items/list***

when they click the "add" button...they are navigated to

***#/items/add***

after they save, they are navigated to

***#/items/99*** (where 99 is the new item id.)

When they click the back button from here, I want them to arrive back at

***#/items/list***

Comment: I suppose if all else fails, I could use javascript to do the locate.replace, right?

Comment: I'm interested in silverlight navigation too. I can't give an authorative answer but I was reading this http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to skip a particular url by handling the Navigating event of the Frame and doing something like this in the body of the handler:

```
if (SomehowDecideToSkipThisOne(e))
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Frame.StopLoading();
    Frame.Navigate(uriToRedirectTo);
}
```

However, the problem lies in how to implement SomehowDecideToSkipThisOne because according to MSDN, ["Any navigation request that the user initiates through a Web browser (including using the back or forward button of the Web browser) is represented as a New type of navigation."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.NAVIGATION.NAVIGATIONMODE.BACK%29;k%28BACK%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Therefore, I can't know when the user is actually going "back" when they click the back button on their browser. So, now I think I will decide to skip the usage of this feature especially since I don't need it for SEO. I just thought it would just be a nice enhancement for my intranet app. It's too hard to support properly though in this scenario.

Comment: Actually, I may still use navigation but I won't use it for navigating to "add item" screens.

Comment: The answer is basically, "No".